# sgx disabled by bios but it is enabled

Tags: system-installation, sgx

I am trying to install Ubuntu for the first time. I have a freshly formatted drive and I keep getting this error at launch. I have set sgx to enabled, software decides, and disabled (just to check). I get the same error every time.
I also tried setting TPM to hidden and switched to AHCI from raid mode. Cleared all passwords and boot keys. There are literally no other bios options to change.

I just want to install Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

SGX is a security nightmare, so don't worry if it's disabled (see: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/08/architectural-bug-in-some-intel-cpus-is-more-bad-news-for-sgx-users/). And SGX has nothing to do with the boot process. And set disks to AHCI if you do not have any RAID disks that you want to share with Windows (99% chances you don't). Please describe your system (model/brand), configuration (CPU, RAM, disks) and Ubuntu (version, on which media, how did you create the boot media, etc.). The better you ask, the best answers you get.